# How can I remove name and dtype from my output list?

Tags: python

I have been doing a program in Python 2 that helps me add all the elements that belong to my list of results, but I had a problem with that list, it is that in my resulting list there are values that are not numbers like "name" and "dtype" by what I can't add them. With this line of code "d = df [df ['radio'] == i] ['ParWeight']" what the program does is rescue the value of the "weight" for a particle that fell within a radius of less than The radio inserted. Each particle corresponds to a radius and its weight

```
import pandas as pd
#Define the data list
weight=[]
data=pd.read_csv('muons.txt',header=0,delim_whitespace=True)
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
#Insert the radio values
R=input('Insert the Radio: ')
for i in df['radio']:
    if i<R:
        d=df[df['radio']==i]['ParWeight']
        weight.append(d) 
print(weight)
[7    2.88072
Name: ParWeight, dtype: float64, 40    5.45978
Name: ParWeight, dtype: float64]
```

Comment: what do you want to do? send `df.head()` so that we can understand what you want to do

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! The reason you're getting name and dtype information is because you're appending a `pandas.series` to your `weight` list. Is that what you intend to do? Or are you only trying to append the value?

Comment: The approach that you used is not efficient, try to do it using `apply` method and `lambda`s

Comment: Sorry, I want to find all the "weight" values for each particle that fell within the radius that I inserted into the code

Answer (score 0):

```
d=df[df['radio']==i]['ParWeight'].iloc[0]
weight.append(d)
print(weight)
```

iloc SHOULD be able to isolate the string value here. I was not able to test due to not have a df available.